# Do the square brackets null the variable?

Tags: php

what does this line do in php?

```
this->$xyz=[];
```

Does this zero out or null the value of $xyz ?

Comment: That line *probably* generates an error and dies horribly... `$this->xyz=[]` maybe, or `$this->{$xyz}=[]` (if it's a variable variable) - what it looks like it's *supposed* to be doing is setting the value of a class member to an empty array.

Comment: it makes it into an (empty) array

Comment: @treyBake I think CD001 is pointing out that without a `$` on `this` it's not gonna do much in PHP.

Comment: @ceejayoz ah I misread the code, just read it as how it should be derp

Comment: One wonders why you did not just try it and find out for yourself?

Comment: typo on my part   remove the $     And RiggsFolly I did and couldn't so I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This make $xyz as an empty array. if you will vardump $xyz, you will see that it is an array type without having any value.

Comment: Side note: It should probably be `->xyz`, not `->$xyz`.